# Eclipse - How to utilize my installed plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I recently installed several eclipse plugins (see image).
 The common for all of them is that I cannot find the way of using them.

[image]

I didn't find none of them on any menu bar item or context menu or even in the preferences dialog.

I use Neon 2 version of eclipse.

---

Update:

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Optimizer for Eclipse is under Help and should appear at Eclipse startup if you are not fully optimized, FindBugs and PMD are views but also FindBugs analysis can be launched by right clicking on a project. In fact all plugins features have different way to be accessed that are specific to the plugin features, just read the plugin documentation.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope Thanks. I updated the question with prints of my help menu and the project context menu. At least I cannot find any evidence there for any plugin whats so ever...